Understanding Flutter's ValueKey
Somewhere in my Flutter app I have a widget with this in its build method:
Stack(children: _loadTestWidgets())

When calling setState, if the _loadTestWidgets method is the following:
List<TestWidget> _loadTestWidgets() {

  return [
    const TestWidget("1"),
    const TestWidget("2"),
    const TestWidget("3")
  ];
}

My TestWidgets are not rebuilt, as expected. If I update the _loadTestWidgets method this way replacing const constructors by keys:
List<TestWidget> _loadTestWidgets() {

  List<TestWidget> result = [];

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    result.add(TestWidget(key: ValueKey<String>("test-widget-$i"), "$i"));
  }

  return result;
}

My widgets are rebuilt on every setState call. Why is that? Shouldn't the ValueKey prevent them to be rebuilt? If I add a key to the whole Stack widget the behaviour is the same.
Here's the TestWidget class:
class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  final String datasetId;

  const TestWidget(this.datasetId, {super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() { return TestWidgetState(); }
}

class TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {

  static final log = Logger('TestWidgetState');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    log.info("build");
    return const Text("hello");
  }
}


Keys don't prevent rebuilds, they just tell Flutter how to link State objects back to the correct Widget objects during rebuilds. This video from the Flutter team does a good job explaining what keys do and how to use them.
But why do stateful Widgets with the same key rebuild?
Just having the same key doesn't mean other properties on the Widget haven't changed. Consider a StatefulWidget like the following:
class MyExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyExample({super.key, required this.cursorColor});

  final Color cursorColor;

  @override
  State<MyExample> createState() => _MyExampleState();
}

class _MyExampleState extends State<MyExample> {
  late final TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: _controller,
      cursorColor: widget.cursorColor,
    );
  }
}

We need the widget to rebuild whenever color changes, regardless of whether key changed (or is even provided).
But then how do I prevent subtree rebuilds?
By using identical (not just equal) Widget instances. The only way Flutter can guarantee a Widget hasn't changed and therefore doesn't need to be rebuilt is if you reuse the exact same instance of that Widget between builds. That's why the first version of your code avoided the rebuild: you were using const constructors, which always return the same instance. Your updated code triggered rebuilds not because of the keys, but because you stopped using const constructors to accommodate constructing your keys and widgets in a loop.
If you can't use const constructors but still need to optimize a widget subtree, the other option is to cache the widget instances inside State and reuse them between builds. Going back to your example, you could theoretically retain the list of TestWidgets between builds and only replace the instances that need to be updated, but that seems error prone and could bloat the parent widget with extra code for that in-place update logic. I would recommend pushing the caching down to TestWidgetState:
class TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  static final log = Logger('TestWidgetState');

  Widget? _child;

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant TestWidget oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    // If your widget has properties that might change and require a rebuild,
    // check for those here and wipe the cached subtree when it happens.
    if (oldWidget.whatever != widget.whatever) {
      _child = null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    log.info("build");
    _child ??= _buildChild();
    return _child!;
  }

  Widget _buildChild() {
    log.info("buildChild");
    return const Text("hello");
  }
}

Further reading:

The "Performance Considerations" section of the StatefulWidget docs
Docs for the child property of ListenableBuilder, which exists to provide a similar optimization


Yes I know that when using const widgets are not rebuilt, but they shouldn't either when using keys, isn't it? If not, what is the purpose of the keys?

Just to associate State with the correct Widget when the widgets might change position within the parent. This video explains it pretty well.

Thanks for the link, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Adding a key should prevent the widget to be rebuilt, right?

"Adding a key should prevent the widget to be rebuilt, right?"
No, that's not what keys are for. I've updated my answer with a more in-depth explanation and some example code.
